# how to keep track of how many total records have been in the table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have to Write one or more triggers that keep track of how many total records have been in the sakila_film table in a single variable, but I am having trouble figuring out how to do this trigger the table is taken from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure-tables-film.html .This is what I have tried the code below but I am getting an error and I don't know any other way i could do it.

```
create trigger records after Update on sakila_film Count(*) from sakila_film;
```

Comment: How do you insert records into he sakila_film table table? do you do that via stored procedure or via script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you planning on storing this count of total rows in the `film` table?

If you are going to manage this with triggers, it seems like you'd need two triggers. One for INSERT, one for DELETE. An UPDATE statement won't change the number of rows in the table. (Note that triggers are NOT fired for foreign key actions; which is a concern if there's a foreign defined with a DELETE rule.) And the triggers will not be fired for a TRUNCATE statement.

Setting aside those concerns, we'd need somewhere to store the rowcount over time. As an example:

```
CREATE TABLE rowcount_history_film 
( ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
, rowcount INT NOT NULL
, KEY rowcount_history_film_IX1 (ts)
) Engine=MyISAM;
```

And then we could use trigger to insert a row into that table whenever a DML statement changes the number of rows in the `film` table:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER film_ad
AFTER DELETE ON film
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO rowcount_history_film (ts, rowcount)
   SELECT NOW(), COUNT(*) FROM film;
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER film_ai
AFTER INSERT ON film
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO rowcount_history_film (ts, rowcount)
   SELECT NOW(), COUNT(*) FROM film;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```